Python Data - Insert Subtotals in original dataframe
I have a Personnel dataframe as follows:

I'm trying to add sub-totals to the dataframe every 3 rows. The end result should look like:

Is there a way to do this efficiently? I tried using a groupby to get a subtotal dataframe and then iteratively loop through the Personnel dataframe and adding in each sub-total row one by one,but there must be a better way?
Similarly, if I want to get the sub-totals by Country, is there a way to efficiently add to the original dataframe?
e.g.
subtotal_df = personnel_df.groupby(personnel_df.index // 3).sum(numeric_only=False)
for idx, row in personnel_df.copy().iterrows():
    pass


I'm sure it's possible to create the dataframe you want with the interspersed subtotal rows, but my experience with pandas is that you REALLY want keep your table simple and consistent.
The table you start with has one row per person, and one column for each attribute of that person. This is the format that pandas expects and we can use all the great pandas tools like groupby etc.
The table with the subtotals doesn't have this simple explanation and doing any pandas operations with that table will be painful.
Instead I'd suggest adding new columns to keep track of the subtotals
import pandas as pd

#create your input table
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['UK','UK','US','US','FR','FR','FR','FR','SWE','SWE'],
    'Name':['Tony','Alan','Lee','David','Steve','Paul','Micky','George','Nigel','John'],
    'Salary':[50,45,60,35,65,48,62,80,64,42],
    'Age':[18.00,16.77,65.53,76.17,77.80,72.82,78.07,46.72,83.83,96.22],
})

#create a new column which will be 0 for the first 3 rows, then 1 for the next 3, etc
df['subtotal_group'] = df.index//3

#use the new column to group and sum subtotals
df['salary_subtotal'] = df.groupby('subtotal_group')['Salary'].transform('sum')
df['age_subtotal'] = df.groupby('subtotal_group')['Age'].transform('sum')

#get subtotals by country in the same way
df['country_salary_total'] = df.groupby('Country')['Salary'].transform('sum')

print(df)


You can always delete the subtotal_group column if you don't like it!

You can also try something like this:
# Add an additional column specifying the number of rows you want to summarize
summarize_rows = 3
j=0
group = []
for i in range(len(df)):
  if i%summarize_rows == 0:
    j+=1
    group.append(j)
  else:
    group.append(j)
df['group'] = group

#Enter Group Criteria
group_by ='group'
# Create Subtotal Row
dfs=[]


for _, d in df.groupby(group_by, as_index=False):
    d.loc['Total', 'Salary'] = df[df[group_by] == _]['Salary'].sum()
    d.loc['Total', 'Age'] = df[df[group_by] == _]['Age'].sum()
    d.loc['Total', 'Name'] = 'SumTotal'
    d.loc['Total', 'group'] = ''
    d.loc['Total', 'Country'] = ''
    dfs.append(d)
    

pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

# Drop the extra column
df_new = df_new.drop(columns=['group'])
df_new

Output:
    Country Name    Salary  Age group
0   UK  Tony    50.0    18.0    1.0
1   UK  Alan    60.0    19.0    1.0
2   US  Lee 70.0    20.0    1.0
3       SumTotal    180.0   57.0    
4   US  David   80.0    21.0    2.0
5   FR  Steve   90.0    22.0    2.0
6   FR  Paul    100.0   23.0    2.0
7       SumTotal    270.0   66.0    
8   FR  Micky   110.0   24.0    3.0
9   FR  George  120.0   25.0    3.0
10  SWE Nigel   130.0   26.0    3.0
11      SumTotal    360.0   75.0    
12  SWE John    140.0   27.0    4.0
13      SumTotal    140.0   27.0    

For Obtaining subtotals by Country:
#Enter Group Criteria
group_by ='Country'

Output:
Country Name    Salary  Age
0   FR  Steve   90.0    22.0
1   FR  Paul    100.0   23.0
2   FR  Micky   110.0   24.0
3   FR  George  120.0   25.0
4       SumTotal    420.0   94.0
5   SWE Nigel   130.0   26.0
6   SWE John    140.0   27.0
7       SumTotal    270.0   53.0
8   UK  Tony    50.0    18.0
9   UK  Alan    60.0    19.0
10      SumTotal    110.0   37.0
11  US  Lee 70.0    20.0
12  US  David   80.0    21.0
13      SumTotal    150.0   41.

